# How to make an isometric background?

Tags: javascript, isometric

I'm trying to create an isometric background for a game but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm using Javascript and jQuery. I've already  [**tried it before**](http://davidsalcedo.com/lab/juego) using CSS3 but I think I'm using the wrong method.

Comment: Hi and welcome to gamdev.SE. Your question lacks a lot of detail. What do you need help with? What look are you aiming for? You should improve your question to avoid downvotes/closing.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about jQuery but in general terms I can think of a few alternatives.

1. Use [**isometric tiles**](http://www.miniwizardstudios.com/iso-tiles.asp) to create the background. It's very similar to creating a top-down tile based map but with tiles being offset a little. You can find more information [*here*](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/%7Ead/jg/ch064/ch6-4.pdf). Also check [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/22279/11686) for a side-by-side comparison between isometric and top-down.

   [image]
2. Turn a top-down background into isometric by **rotating 45º and compressing it vertically**, either in code or in some [image manipulation software](http://www.gimp.org/).

   [image]
3. Probably not applicable here but in a 3D API you can also get an isometric view of the world by setting an **orthographic projection** and positioning the camera at the correct angle.

Comment: i know how to do it (rotate 45° and compressing) with css or tiles on png. But my really question talk about how distribute uniformly the tiles.

Comment: @david When did you mention tiles in your question? I had to make the assumption and talk about all the possibilities. And have you read [the document I linked](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/ch064/ch6-4.pdf) about isometric tiles? It talks about your problem on page 15.

Comment: ok, i use jQuery, and my idea it's make a isometric floor. i read about tiles here: http://www.cw-internetdienste.de/2010/05/creating-a-basic-isometric-map/ but this script doesn´t works me, the tiles don't maintained in the site.